# Node global config vs import config

Tags: javascript, node.js

What will be the difference between storing config in global variable vs exporting config from a module and importing where ever required?

For example

*Storing against global*

```
//config.js
global.appconfig = {
  key: 'xxxxx',
  domain: 'www.abc.com'
}

//app.js
function app() {
  const config = global.appconfig
  //do something
}
```

vs

exporting from a module and importing where ever required

```
//config.js
export default {
  key: 'xxxxx',
  domain: 'www.abc.com'
}

//app.js
import appconfig from './config.js';

function app() {
  const config = appconfig;
  //do something
}
```

Few benefits of using the second way which i can think of

- global config can be tempered, where tempering imports will not affect other modules.
- global is tightly couple with node ecosystem where as imports can easily be used for browser/client js as well.

My only worry is memory allocation in case of imports.

Comment: adding stuff to the global is a bad practise, same as adding stuff to the `window` object in the browser. Stick to the export/import

Comment: Your `global` example is missing the part where you `require` your config module

Comment: @Bergi That can be done at start of the application itself.

Comment: @yBrodsky - What if config is required by most of the module for some or the other key from config. From performance point of view will there be no difference?

Comment: I don't think so. It's cached in memory

Comment: @thecachedbyte Yes, but where in particular? I just meant to say that for a proper comparison you should have two snippets that actually do the same things.

Comment: What about something like configuration that you are querying from a database or api?  I don't want to have to retrieve it again each import.